# Is there a side effect if I call module.exports.public_method inside a private method in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, recursion, settimeout

I'm wondering if this is the correct way of doing recursive `setTimeout` in Node.js?

```
module.exports = {
  connect: function(callback) {
    amqp.connect(config.queue.url, function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("[AMQP]", err.message);
        return setTimeout(module.exports.connect, 1000); // keep reconnecting
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a reconnecting mechanism in Node.js. But I'm not sure if this line is going to have a side effect in JavaScript? `return setTimeout(module.exports.connect, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine but i think you should improve your code to allow notification of the caller of the connection attempt (even if you perform reconnection).